# How to assign System.Type and object values from c#.net to protobuf

Tags: grpc, protobuf-net, grpc-c#, protocol-buffers-3

`google.protobuf.Type Type = 1;`

Using below code I am trying to assign the value which is system.type to WellKnownTypes.Type.

scanParameter.Type = (Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Type)parameter.ValueDataType;

It is giving me compile time error saying Invalid Cast.

how to handle this

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can just cast a C# object to a Google Protobuf Type. If you check the documentation, type expects [a protocol buffer message type](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#type).  So you need to define a protobuf message type, generate C# code from that with [protoc](https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/), then you have your type (and can implement how an conversion would work if you want to cast).

Comment: Also, since you tagged [protobuf-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net), using that you could just define the C# types that you want to use in gRPC. You do not need to cast to Protobuf types using that framework.